# How to subtract seconds from postgres datetime

Tags: postgresql

Say I have column of type dateTime with value "2014-04-14 12:17:55.772" & I need to subtract seconds "2" seconds from it to get o/p like this "12:17:53".

Answer (score 22):

```
select '2014-04-14 12:17:55.772'::timestamp - interval '2 seconds';
```

For greater flexibility it is possible to mutiply the interval

```
select '2014-04-14 12:17:55.772'::timestamp - 2 * interval '1 second';
```

If you want to truncate to the second

```
select date_trunc(
    'second', 
    '2014-04-14 12:17:55.772'::timestamp - interval '2 seconds'
);
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it & it's working fine but my with this approach I am facing group by clause issue. I updated the problem statement & descrption. Please have a look

Comment: created different thread related to  this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23063314/how-to-subtract-seconds-from-postgres-datetime-without-having-to-add-it-in-group

Answer (score 6):

Postgres does not have a `dateTime` data type. I assume you mean a `timestamp`.

You can subtract an "interval" with the desired length from that column:

```
select the_timestamp_column - interval '2' second
from the_table
```

More about intervals [in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT)

More about the operators available for `date` and `timestamp` columns [in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html)

Comment: Thanks. I tried it & it's working fine but my with this approach I am facing group by clause issue. I updated the problem statement & descrption. Please have a look

Comment: @user1298426: that is a completely new question now.

Comment: created different thread related to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23063314/how-to-subtract-seconds-from-postgres-datetime-without-having-to-add-it-in-group