# How to subtract seconds from postgres datetime without having to add it in group by clause?

Tags: postgresql

Say I have column of type dateTime with value "2014-04-14 12:17:55.772" & I need to subtract seconds "2" seconds from it to get o/p like this "12:17:53".

```
userid  EndDate                 seconds
--------------------------------------------------------
1   "2014-04-14 12:17:14.295"   512
1   "2014-04-14 12:31:14.295"   12
2   "2014-04-14 12:48:14.295"   2
2   "2014-04-14 13:22:14.295"   12
```

& the query is

```
select (enddate::timestamp - (seconds* interval '1 second')) seconds, userid
from user
group by userid
```

Now I need to group by userid only but enddate & seconds added to select query that is asking me to add it in group by clause which will not give me correct o/p.

I am expecting data in this format where I need to calculate start_time from end_time & total seconds spent.

```
    user : 1

  start_time            end_time        total (seconds)
      "12:17"           "12:17"             1
      "12:22"           "12:31"            512
                                       total:   513 
  user : 2
      "12:43"           "12:48"         288
      "13:22"           "13:22"         1
                                       total    289
```

Is there some way i could avoid group by clause in this?

Comment: So which `enddate` do you want for multiple userid's? You need to pick *one* otherwise your `group by` doesn't make any sense

Comment: I updated the ticket on my expected o/p.

Comment: `GROUP BY user_id` doesn't mean "put all the records for one `user_id` next to each other" (that would be `ORDER BY user_id`) it means "return exactly one row for each `user_id`".

Comment: In general, you can have the total for each user (with `GROUP BY`, 2 rows in your example) or the individual start and end times of each entry (without `GROUP BY`, 4 rows in your example), but not both at once. There are some tricks to calculate both at once, such as Window functions, but they can be fiddly if you're new to SQL, so it's often simpler to get the individual rows, and calculate running totals in the application layer (PHP, or whatever you're using to actually display the data).

Comment: I am adding group_by on user_id because I need to calculate total_time based on user_id. As per query if I add enddate & seconds in group by then it will return seperate total_time for each row which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @IMSoP says, you can use a window function to include a total for each user in your query output:

```
SELECT userid
     , (enddate - (seconds * interval '1 second')) as start_time
     , enddate as end_time
     , seconds
     , sum(seconds) OVER (PARTITION BY userid) as total
  FROM so23063314.user;
```

Then you would only display the parts of the row you're interested in for each subtotal line, and display the total at the end of each block.