# PostgreSQL: How subtract dates in two consecutive rows which are in two different columns?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, subtraction

I need to subtract two dates from each other (start_time(n+1)-end_time(n)) which are in two different rows and columns by partitioning with id. Look at the table below:

```
row |id|    Start_time       |      end_time
----+--+---------------------+------------------------
 1  |14|"2012-06-16 21:43:00"|"2012-06-16 23:54:00"
 2  |14|"2012-06-19 13:09:00"|"2012-06-19 23:59:00"
 3  |21|"2016-04-12 14:46:00"|"2016-04-25 13:55:00"
 4  |21|"2016-04-20 09:35:00"|"2016-04-20 22:00:00"
 5  |24|"2011-09-19 19:20:00"|"2011-09-19 22:15:00"
 6  |24|"2011-09-20 19:01:00"|"2011-09-22 14:05:00"
 7  |30|"2009-10-21 07:25:00"|"2009-10-21 10:59:00"
 8  |30|"2009-10-27 16:01:00"|"2009-11-10 16:00:00"
 9  |30|"2009-10-28 08:13:00"|"2009-10-28 23:59:00"
10  |36|"2015-11-23 12:21:00"|"2015-11-23 15:19:00"
```

Example: for id=14, I need to subtract end_time in row 1 from start_time in row 2, and store the result in a new column. My main purpose is that to find the time difference between each measurement for every ids. 
Is it possible at all?

My preferred results would be like diff column:

```
row |id|    Start_time       |      end_time       |   diff   
----+--+---------------------+---------------------+------------
 1  |14|"2012-06-16 21:43:00"|"2012-06-16 23:54:00"| 
 2  |14|"2012-06-19 13:09:00"|"2012-06-19 23:59:00"|"2 days 13:15:00"
 3  |21|"2016-04-12 14:46:00"|"2016-04-25 13:55:00"|
 4  |21|"2016-04-20 09:35:00"|"2016-04-20 22:00:00"|"-5 days -04:20:00"
 5  |24|"2011-09-19 19:20:00"|"2011-09-19 22:15:00"|
 6  |24|"2011-09-20 19:01:00"|"2011-09-22 14:05:00"|"20:46:00"
```

Comment: use `lag()`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

Comment: you can fine same ans here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23062402/how-to-subtract-seconds-from-postgres-datetime

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name please see my updated question. I need to calculate start_time (n+1) - end_time(n) for every id, which n is number of row.

Comment: @AkankhaAhmed please see the results that I am looking for.

Comment: That's exactly what `lag()` is for:  `start_time - lag(end_time) over (order by start_time)`, or using `lead()` lead(start_time) over (...) - end_time`

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name. I finally figured out how lag function works here. This is my code that works:   start_time - lag(end_time) over (PARTITION BY id order by start_time) as diff;.